# cannot get second row->first column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot get the second row->first column value using this function:

```
$("#clear").on("click", function(){
    var curKey = $(this).closest("tr").children("td#key").text();
    alert (curKey);
});
```

With this html:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="key">1</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clear">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="key">2</td>
    <td>Some More Text</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clear">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Clicking on the first "delete" alerts a value of 1... second "delete" does nothing.

Here's a fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denikov/HwxVQ/)

Comment: Duplicate ids!!! Change to class.

Comment: Wow...I'm an idiot...you live and you learn.  Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple items with the same `id`. Try using a `class` instead:

```js
$(".clear").on("click", function() {
  var curKey = $(this).closest("tr").children(".key").text();
  console.log(curKey);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="key">1</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clear">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="key">2</td>
    <td>Some More Text</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clear">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[IDS ARE UNIQUE](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class), you can not have the same id on the page more than once. Use a class.

```
<td class="key">1</td>
```

and change the selector

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".key").text();
```

Same thing with the buttons, use a class.

You can avoid the whole tree reversal by using a data attribute!

HTML:

```
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clear" data-id="1">Delete</a></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("table tbody").on("click", "a.clear", function(){
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Comment: You *can* have the same id, but you **shouldnt** :)